# Ribbon Menu Android

Tags: android, animation, menu

I read somewhere that Google called this "Ribbon menu".

Anyway this is what I mean (also take a look at this [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170821195646/http://www.androiduipatterns.com:80/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html)):

[image: Ribbon menu]

This is Google+ app. When you click the G+ icon on the ActionBar, the entire screen moves right and a menu comes out. Note that the ActionBar also moves.

I want to do this in my application, but I don't know how. I have basic understanding of the animation framework.

The questions are:

- What kind of layout I have to use?
- How to animate the *entire* screen (with the ActionBar)?

I hope these are not too generic questions. I'm asking for examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's a first step but not exactly what I was asking for. In your example the ribbon menu comes from the left. I was asking for the entire screen moving to the right, discovering the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it. It's simple.

```
getWindow().getDecorView();
```

This line gives you the main View of your activity. The main view contains all the things that are displayed in the activity. Then you can animate it. The answer was simple.

This link helped me a lot: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658

### EDIT:

This is not the way to proceed. Like Cyril Mottier said it's a hack and I found a lot of problems.
I redid everything and now I'm implementing my own ActionBar.

Comment: Animating is one thing ... Adding a View in the decor View is another (ie a hack). As I said in my article, using the decor View is a hack you shouldn't use. Google+ (just like we do in Prixing) actually uses a custom implementation of the ActionBar that lives in the android.R.id.content View.

Comment: Yes, it's a hack. I tried casting `decorView` to `FrameLayout` and then I added the `View` for the menu. It worked for a while. But now there are a lot of problems. :( Now I'm implementing my own ActionBar. It's time to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for this. Another name for the same thing is **Slideout navigation**.
Here are the solutions I've found on Github:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation

Comment: https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu has been previously suggested by SpK (in a comment) and it's not what I was looking for. I'll try the other one and I'll tell you what I think. Thank you for the reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Navigation Drawer very well,
Here is a sample that i find it

MainActivity.java

```
package ir.ZiaNazari.navigationdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // 2. App Icon
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            );

    // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // just styling option
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.ic_launcher, GravityCompat.START);

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
     actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
    // then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

    }
}
}
```

drawer_listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="14.5sp"
    android:paddingEnd="14.5sp"
    android:minHeight="35sp" >
</TextView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape"
    >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string> 
    <string-array name="items">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 6</item>
    </string-array> 
    <string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

</resources>
```

I hope this help you and others